# Linearity and Injectivity of Polynomial maps

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have the following Problem and I am not quite sure if I solve it right, could someone help me?

> Investigate if the following map is injective or surjective and prove of linearity .
>
> $l_1$ : $P_2$ ($\mathbb{R}$ ) -> $P_2$ ($\mathbb{R}$ )  ,$l_1$($p$)=:=($p') ^2$ , where  $p'$ is the derivative of $p$

I know that in order to prove linearity I have to look if the map fullfilts

> $$(p + q)(x) = p(x) + q(x)$$ 
>   $$(\alpha p)(x) = \alpha(p(x))$$
>
> So  if  we say $$l_1(p)=l_2(p) =x$$  then
>   $$(l_1 +l_2)(p) =(p_1')^2 +( p_2')^2=1 +1 = 2 $$
>   so it is not linear.

and in order to check injectivity we have :

> $$f(x)=f(y), x=y$$
>   $$ l_1(p)= l_1(q)$$
>   $$(p_1')^2=(q_1')^2$$
>   and if we take square root then $p_1'=q_1'$, so the map is injective

Comment: Your have to prove that $p(x+y)=p(x)+p(y)$ in your first task for linearity, not what you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all consider $p=x^{2}$ and $q=-x^{2}$, then $l_{1}(p)=4x^{2}=l_{1}(q)$ so $l_{1}$ is not injective. Also note that there is no polynomial $p$ such that $l_{1}(p)=x(x-1)$, so $l_{1}$ is not surjective. Finally note that 
$$l_{1}(p+q)=(p')^{2}+(q')^{2}+2p'q'=l_{1}(p)+l_{1}(q)+2p'q'$$
so $l_{1}$ is not linear.